# Replacing certain words in a cstring

Tags: c, c-strings

I have a test driver that I am given that will randomly generate a string of words and will randomly pick a replacement word for me to replace with another randomly picked word.

My code gets the number of changes correct and can find and remove the picked word but in most cases I am left with an extra space after the correction and I can't figure out why that is happening.

```
int replaceText(char *line, char * const word, const char * const repl)
  {
    char * location = strstr(line, word);
    int wordLength = strlen(word),
        counter = 0,
        delSpace = 0;

    while(location)
    {
        counter++;
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++)
        {
            *(location + i) = ' ';
            delSpace++;
            if (i <= wordLength)
            {
                for (int j = 0;j<wordLength;j++)
                {
                    for(int shiftChar = 0;shiftChar<=(wordLength - delSpace);shiftChar++)
                    {
                        line[j] = line[j+1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        *location=*repl;
        location = strstr(line, word);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Also the test driver I have linked in my compiler automatically outputs all text.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw a very similar question earlier today ... anyway, how about adding some sample inputs and their respective outputs?

Comment: BTW `int j = 0;`...`line[j] = line[j+1];` this is wrong.

Comment: OK.. What's wrong about it and how do I fix it?

Comment: _What's wrong about it_ Always replace  the head of the character in the rest of the characters. To rethink the algorithm. (or search it)